# What is wrong with this POST request with json on android?

Tags: android, json, post

I'm trying to perform a POST request to a server that wants the Content-Type set to application/json with name and email as some keys.  Currently, I'm getting a 406 error, which I'm assuming is working on the server side, but android can't handle the response.  How can I tweak the code to get a 200 response?

```
HttpClient client = new DefaultHttpClient();
HttpEntity entity;

try{
    JSONObject j = new JSONObject();
    j.put("name" , myName);
    j.put("email", myEmail);

    HttpPost post = new HttpPost(targetURL);
    post.setHeader("Content-Type", "application/json");

    StringEntity se = new StringEntity(j.toString(), HTTP.UTF_8);
    se.setContentType("application/json");
    post.setEntity(se);

    HttpResponse response = client.execute(post);
    entity = response.getEntity();

    Log.d("response", response.getStatusLine().toString());
} catch(Exception e){Log.e("exception", e.toString());}
```

Does that look about right?  Do I need one of those response handlers when creating the HttpClient?

Comment: What server are you posting to? Do you control it, or have the code for it? Can you check what the server receives? If you don't have access to the server and/or its code, you might want to set up a Tomcat instance on your development machine and test with that.

Comment: are the JSON key names correct? are there additional headers you should be sending?

Comment: unfortunately, I don't have access to the server.  I also don't know if I need to be sending other headers (such as this accept header)

Comment: Try specify parameter **Accept** in request header as well: post.setHeader("Accept", "application/json");

Answer (score 0):

This works for me with json-2.0.jar

```
        HttpClient client = new DefaultHttpClient();
        HttpConnectionParams.setConnectionTimeout(client.getParams(), MyApplication.HTTP_TIMEOUT); //Timeout Limit
        HttpResponse response;
        ArrayList<appResults> arrayList = new ArrayList<appResults>();
        String resul;
        try{

            HttpGet get = new HttpGet(urls[0]);


            response = client.execute(get);
            /*Checking response */
            if(response!=null){
                InputStream in = response.getEntity().getContent(); //Get the data in the entity
                resul = convertStreamToString(in);
                Gson gson = new Gson();                 
                Type listType = new TypeToken<ArrayList<appResults>>() {}.getType();
                arrayList = gson.fromJson(resul, listType);
                in.close();
```

of course in asynctask or thread.
But 406... it seems that your format on your webserver and your app are not consistent...

Comment: No matter what `converStreamToString()` does, it can't be correct. Please use [EntityUtils.toString(response.getEntity())](http://developer.android.com/reference/org/apache/http/util/EntityUtils.html#toString(org.apache.http.HttpEntity)) because it's less code and obeys the character encoding sent by the server.

Comment: the only thing is that you're performing a get request.  Should I just switch that to HttpPost?